# findViewById is returning null inside run method (android)

Tags: java, android, xml, runnable

for some reason the run method here has no trouble setting the content view, but when i try to retrieve the button from the xml it returns null and does not allow me to set the onclick listener. my code is listed here below.

```
v.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        setContentView(R.layout.win);
        Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                HighScoresHelper scores = new HighScoresHelper("HighScoreV2.txt", GameActivity.this);
                scores.addScore("Test", Math.round((frame/FPS) *100)/100.0);
                startActivity(new Intent(GameActivity.this, HighScores.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

and yes, the spelling and everything is all correct and matches up with the xml, here is the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="YOU WON!!!, enter in your name and click submit"
    android:id="@+id/textView3" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/name" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Thank you

Comment: Is `R` from your application or from the `android` namespace?

Comment: @Eun it would not compile if it were the android namespace. `id.submit` and `layout.win` don't exist under that namespace.

Comment: that xml is exactly the content of `layout/win.xml`? did you try to clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: @njzk2 After a clean and rebuild everything compiled just fine.

Comment: Please show all the relevant code (so we could see the entire class hierarchy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was that I was calling this inside the inner-class to the activity. What I needed to do was inflate the view and save it as a global variable. I did all of this inside the onCreate method.

```
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            winView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.win, null);
            submit = (Button) winView.findViewById(R.id.submitScore);

            submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
```

and then inside my inner class I called

```
v.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        setContentView(winView);
                    }
                });
```

to change the view when necessary, v was the inner-class instance variable of the main class.

Just to clarify, main class - "GameActivity" and the inner-class was labeled "OurView". v was a global varible of type OurView inside the class GameActivity. I would post the entire class, but its 300+ lines long.